# Android convention to denote method UI thread safety

Tags: android, multithreading, ui-thread

Android documentation, tutorials, videos and the like are filled with best practice on how to avoid non-essential processing on the UI thread. However, when creating a big app or using external components it can be hard to remember which methods block the UI thread and which do not. I've often seen threading mentioned in comments, but that seems error prone for lazy/rushed situations, and not everything gets an ideal code review.

What naming, annotation, or other conventions exist to help developers quickly determine if the methods they are considering are UI thread optimized or not?